# Exclusão via regex

Tags: xml, regex

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
2014-10-12 17:04:29.996
```

É um formato `timestamp` e está errado pois após a hora existe o `.996`. Para capturar este trecho usei a `regex` :

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2,3}
```

Como posso remover somente o final levando em consideração que tenho muitas ocorrências ?

Comment: vc abriu o xml em um editor de texto e quer remover o microsegundo?

Comment: Exatamente isso, posso ter explicado mal a pergunta.

Comment: Preciso salvar a primeira parte pra dar um replace removendo o que não quero.

Comment: A resposta não resolveu? a sua string está entre tags?

Comment: Está assim: `DT_HR_ALTERACAO="2015-02-05 10:55:01.324"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para capturar o microsegundo pode usar a seguinte regex `\.\d+(")$` ela diz para capturar no final da string um ponto seguido de um ou mais dígitos seguido de uma aspa dupla que é um grupo. No campo de substituição coloque `\1` ou `$1` é o valor do grupo captura no caso a aspa dupla.

=> **^** captura no exemplo:

```
DT_HR_ALTERACAO="2015-02-05 10:55:01.324"
                                    ^^^^^
```

Imagino que ele seja capturado para ser substituido por alguma outra coisa.

Comment: Assim que eu testar eu te retorno, obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Em sublime: selecionar exp.regulates e:

```
find=    (DT_HR_ALTERACAO="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\.\d{2,3}
replace= \1
```

Em linha de comando:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/...find anterior.../$1/g' ex.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando o sed fica assim:

```
sed -r 's/\.[0-9]{3}"$//' nome-arquivo >> novo-arquivo
```

Adaptado da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187418/57573) do @rray

Comment: já agora `> novo-arquivo` ou então `>> velho` ☺